# how to transform map in jpg format into data.frame that can be fed into geom_polygon or geom_sf?

Tags: r, ggplot2, jpeg

I have an image in jpg format:
[image]

As you can see there are tiles and number associated with them. I would like to extract the tiles' boundary into polygon, in any format that can be supplied into geom_polygon or geom_sf so that I can make a number of [choropleth map](https://datavizcatalogue.com/methods/choropleth.html).

I am not sure whether R is the right tool to do this and I don't know where to start.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible but I could be wrong. You may want to use ArcMap for this purpose by using digitizing (Just a thought).

Comment: Yeap, I think there is no easy method to do it in R, a possible scripting way to do this [gdal_polygonize](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html). However, I found another data source in geojson format which solved my problem.